# Searching for srvany.exe from Windows 7 Resource Kit: is this actual software or just a book?

Tags: windows, service

I'm looking for a version of the *Windows Resource Kit* supported on Windows 7. But I'm having a hard time finding a download location or any information on where to get that software from (e.g. installation CDs for the OS or IDE).

When searching for "windows 7 resource kit" on Google, I get a lot of results for this book from Microsoft Press:

http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/book.aspx?id=13811

Do I need to buy this book to get access to the software or is there another way? I just need one executable, *srvany.exe*, from the resource kit. I'm wondering, does this software actually exist?

Comment: You may be able to use [Microsoft Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17657) utilities with Windows 7.

Comment: Consider also https://nssm.cc/ alternative.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

srvany.exe is in Windows 2003 Resource kit tools. This page says that it will work on Windows 7.

http://www.technlg.net/windows/download-windows-resource-kit-tools/

You may also want to add ";C:\Program Files\Windows Resource Kits\Tools" or 
";C:\Program Files\Windows Resource Kits (x84)\Tools" to you path in the Environment Variables options to use it with Command Prompt.

Comment: For what I need, which is registering an running a non-service application as a windows server, it seems to work on Windows 7 (from which I assume it's also going to work in Windows Server 2008). Thanks for the link and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 2):

As long as you are pretending to use an old and **outdated** program like `srvany` on Windows 7, you must know about the possible disadvantages of it:

[SrvAny disadvantages in modern Windows](http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/srvany.html) (extracted from AlwaysUp FAQ, so they are trying to sell you their product ;-) ).

I think there are better options:

1.- The `SC` command (`sc create MyService`).
  2.- The (not free, but makes things a lot easier) [AlwaysUp](http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/) tool, that add multiple features (like log, statistics, checking&restarting your service, email alerts... etc). As long as it has [command-line management](http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/AlwaysUpCLT/), I think it is appropriate to refer it here.

EDIT-1: The AlwaysUp FAQ is supposed to have some outdatings, i.e: it reports SrvAny as non working for Windows7/8 (thanks, @shelleybutterfly).

Comment: it may be a bit outdated, but the page you have linked has misinformation (saying that srvany is not compatible with Windows 8/7, which is not true, see the accepted answer for this question) and is information that is *from a page on the website of the company that sells a competitor to the gratis alternative given by SrvAny* so of course we should expect that the answer will be biased.

Comment: Edited post to reflect. Thanks for pointing, @shelleybutterfly .

Comment: `sc create MyService` will not work if you launch for example a PHP script. This one will hangs on `net start MyService` (because he soes not handle start and stop operations as a real service should do), which is the main reason we could need a `srvany.exe` or equivalent

Answer (score 1):

You can find the "Remote Server Administration Tools for Windows 7 with Service Pack 1 (SP1)" here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7887

Comment: Are the tools provided in the Windows Resource Kit also included in that package? I installed it and could not locate these tools, e.g. srvany.exe.